# From the following mathematical expressions, which are true, which are false and which are ambiguous.

Tags: logic

(a) The square root of an integer is a non negative real number.

(b) There is an angle $\alpha$ that $\sin \alpha = \cos \alpha$.

(c) $x<1$.

(d) If $x<1$, then $x^{2}<1$.

(e) If $x$ is an arbitrary complex number, then $x^{2}-x=1$.

Ambiguous means that its validity or falsity depends on the value of the variables x and y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) False

B) True. (Understanding an angle such as "at least one angle", not "a single angle".

C) Ambiguous.

D) False.

E) False.

Answer (score 1):

(A) is false, because there are integers whose square roots are complex numbers; for example, $-1$.

(B) is true; $\alpha = 45^{\circ}$ is sufficient.

(C) is ambiguous; to show this, you just need to find an $x$ so that $x < 1$ and another so that $x \nless 1$. I'll leave it to you to find those examples.

(D) is false; to prove it, you need an $x < 1$ with $x^2 \geq 1$. Think about extreme cases - in particular, don't limit yourself to positive values of $x$.

(E) is extremely false. Pick a value of $x$ at random, and check whether $x^2 - x = 1$. If not, you have your counterexample. (It's extremely unlikely that you'll pick a value of $x$ for which $x^2 - x = 1$.)